# Where to backup .ENV Files, API Keys, Project Passwords? Any best practices or how do you do it?

Tags: node.js, api, security, environment-variables, backup

I might work in the future with 3rd Party API-Keys that connect to very sensitive information and was thinking about how to back them up.

I was thinking about encrypting some text-document and upload it to some cloud-storage like Dropbox.

Or using something like KeePass:(?)
https://keepass.info/index.html

Any recomondations?
How have you been handling this stuff in your projects?

(in case there is a better place to ask on some stackExchange group, please leave a comment before closing)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/ is for admins - sounds like that's a site you could try. In general the answer will vary very greatly depending on your situation - is this an API key a large multi-national company you work for, or is it your hobby project... in either case, the main thing is that it's secure and that it really is backed up.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a project management software, it should be uploaded there for everyone part of the team to see.

then we just copy and save it to our dev pc when we need it.